# composer update problem with ext-calender * is missing from your system

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, php-extension

Am trying to update composer dependencies on a Laravel application but getting this error

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-calender* is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's calendar extension.

in my composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-calender": "*",
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your operating system? Linux or Mac or windows?

Comment: which linux version or windows version are you using? Install that particular extension

Comment: @CaddyDZ My apologize . Waiting for sithu's reply .

Comment: OS is Ubuntu Linux and i also install sudo apt-get install php7.2-calendar

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just make a mistake in composer.json

instead `"ext-calender": "*",`
it should be `"ext-calendar": "*",`

Wrong spelling 'e' and 'a'